# add map in a fragment Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm trying to add a map in a fragment but the problem is i can't find the id of the mapView

the xml Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/google_map"/>
```

and for the Fragment Code

class ParentTrackFragment : Fragment(),OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private var _binding: FragmentParentTrackBinding? = null
lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
 private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentParentTrackBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root
    val mapFragment = requireActivity().findViewById<MapView>(R.id.google_map)
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    return root

}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap!!
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))

}
```

the problem is it can't find the mapView id "google_map"

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to search for the view in the Activity before your Fragment  has even been attached to that Activity. And since `onCreateView` hasn't even returned yet at the point you search for the view, it's not even available to find in the Fragment yet either.

If you actually needed to search for it at this point, you would call `findViewById` on `binding.root`.

But this would be completely pointless because you're using view binding. Just use `binding.googleMap` to get your view reference. The whole point of view binding is to eliminate the use of `findViewById`.